# How to implement multichat in Django channels

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am implementing a real-time chat functionality using Django channels 3 and Django rest framework, where I have two types of users clients and admins , what I am trying to do is to create for every user a chat room in order to discuss with the admins, I tried to use multiple rooms and it doesn't work because the admin is unaware of the newly created user room , my second choice is to use room_group_name , but so far I don't really understand it, if someone can clarify or help I would be grateful .

Consumer.py

```
    async def connect(self):


        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        print(self.user.is_superuser)
        print(self.user.is_staff)
       

        if self.user.is_superuser:
            self.room_name = "chat"
            self.room_group_name = 'admin_%s' % self.room_name
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name

            )
            await self.accept()



        if self.user.is_client:
            self.room_name = "chat"
            self.room_group_name = 'client_%s'.format(self.user) % self.room_name



            admin = 'admin_%s' % self.room_name
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                # self.room_group_name,
                 self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name

            )

            await self.accept()
```

So far I can separate the two groups, but the trick is how to add admin users to the client group room ??

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but I have few thoughts, maybe it will help. For every client user, you could create a new chat room and record its name in the database, you could do in connect method. Then, you can display list of rooms to the admins and admins will be able to join by clicking on a room. Also, you may want to notify admin users about new rooms in real time using another WS connection for them.

Comment: That exaclty what I did this morning , thank you for sharing